# mysqli query function not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE main_subject = " + echo $_GET['msubject']);
```

The above gives me a parse error. Could you give me suggestions on how I could change it to make it work?

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: @amaia It's a `parse error`. It gives no more detail than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.` instead of `+` for the concatenation.
Replace your script for this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE main_subject = '" . $_GET['msubject'] . "'");
```

Comment: I changed it to `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE main_subject = " . echo $_GET['msubject']);` yet it still gives me a parse error.

Comment: you don't have to add `echo`

Comment: There are several issues. The `echo` cannot be there - you are not producing output, but rather interpolating a variable into the SQL string. Then, assuming it is a string and not a number, it must be single quoted. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql for examples. Most importantly, the variable requires protection from SQL injection See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php#60496

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I understood SQL injection to only be a problem if one is inputting user inputted values into the database. I am only pulling values from the database with user inputs. Would this still be a problem?

Comment: @p789887 Yes, it is still problematic. The query could be modified by injection to return unintended rows, or combined with a `UNION` to reveal other tables from your database. For example - `SELECT * FROM files WHERE main_subject = '' UNION SELECT username, password FROM users`  could be constructed by passing a value through `$_GET`.  Injection vulnerabilities apply to all SQL statements.